# Products not appearing using Create New Items in Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

first of all I couldn't find this specific problem anywhere on StackOverFlow.

I am trying to import products on my Magento website using Magmi. I have a product CSV with me which I exported using Magento DataFlow.

My problem is this, on Magmi, when I select "**Create New Items & Update Existing Items**" or "**Create New Items & Skip Existing**" the SKUs get imported succesfully but they are not visible on the backend. I get no error on Magmi ouput.

However, if I use "**Update Existing Items**" after I have done the above step, the items become visible in the backend. Hence, to make my items visible on backend I have to import twice, first using Create option and second using the Update option.

Could you help me on this problem as I believe this is not how magmi actually works.

Comment: Okay I found it. I had to explicitly set Status to enabled in the csv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it! I had to explicitly mention "status" to enabled in the CSV file.